# To show your comment first if you are logged (and if you left a comment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am editing a Book-page improving the Comments-Area.

Now it is a "classic" area where the latest 3 comments are showed.

**But I want to edit it showing first the comment left by the "logged user" (`current_user`), if it is logged and if he already left a comment in this page, and then the others (excluding the comment by current user already showed).**

Now they are showed using a script in `book_controller.rb`

```
  def load_comments!
    @comments = @book.comments.roots.includes(:user).latest.limit(3)
  end
```

As I said, I have to check if the user is logged and if he already left a comment.

**But I don't know how to merge then the two queries.**

So my first idea was to add first if `current_user`

```
  def load_comments!
    @comments = if current_user
                   @book.comments.roots.includes(:user).where(user: current_user).latest.limit(1).any?
                   + @book.comments.roots.includes(:user).where(user: !current_user).latest.limit(2) 
                else
                   @book.comments.roots.includes(:user).latest.limit(3)
                end
  end
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing won't actually work since the where clause would apply to all the comments.

The most straight forward solution is to just perform a separate query and concatenate the arrays:

```
def last_user_comment
  current_user.comments
              .order(created_at: :desc)
              .where(book: @book)
              .last if current_user
end

def load_comments!
  @comments = @book.comments.roots.then do |base|
    if last_user_comment
      base.limit(2).to_a.unshift(last_user_comment)
    else
      base.limit(3)
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: where can I add limit(3) in 'load_comments!' ? Can I have ":nil issues" for the last_user_comment? (if he never commented the book)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough - if you want muliple comments you can just use concatenation.  `&.any?` might actually be superflous as you can still concatenate an empty ActiveRecord::Relation as you get `[]` when you cast it to an array.

Comment: oh, good. Thanks... But... wait. I am watching your edit. if you add .last(3) there, it will take the latest 3 comments by the CURRENT_USER. I have to take 3 comments max. 1 (by current_user) + 2 (by other users) or (if there are no comments by the current_user) only 3 by other users.

Comment: Gotcha. Basically the same thing but slightly different logic.

Comment: damn. it doesn't work. And on my local host I can see only "error 500". I don't see where is the bug... any idea?